# How do I configure Log4Net to ignore 404 errors?

Tags: asp.net, logging, exception, log4net

Http 404 errors are clogging up my log files. It's true I need to resolve the 404 errors, but doing so is a task in and of itself. I will use a tool like Fiddler for hunting down the 404's but I do not want them logged.

Answer (score 2):

a 404 is thrown as an instance of System.Web.HttpException. If you are trapping/logging exceptions in `global.asax`, something like this should do the trick:

```
protected void Application_Error( object sender , EventArgs e )
{
  Exception     exceptionInstance = Server.GetLastError() ;
  HttpException httpException     = exceptionInstance as HttpException ;
  int?          httpStatusCode    = ( httpException != null ? httpException.GetHttpCode() : (int?)null ) ;

  if ( !httpStatusCode.HasValue || httpStatusCode != 404 )
  {
    LogExceptionHere() ;
  }

  return ;

}
```

If you're using [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) (and you [should be](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx)), you need to configure it to ignore 404s in your web.config. Something along these lines:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <elmah>
    ...
    <errorFilter>
      <test>
        <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
      </test>
    </errorFilter>
    ...
  </elmah>
  ...
</configuration>
```